# Pydata Seattle - Implementing and Training Predictive Customer Lifetime Value Models in Python

Tags: python, lifetimes-python

Can someone point me to the **PyData Seattle notebook for Implementing and Training Predictive Customer Lifetime Value Models in Python**? It seems oracle bought datascience.com and now the notebook isn't available on the provided Github link anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link that works in 2022: https://github.com/dataandcaffeine/pydata-seattle-2017/tree/master/lifetime-value

Comment: you are right, i missed that part. thank you for pointing that out